# Why do we need the Lync SDK Controls, if they can not be used in UI Suppression mode?

Tags: lync

Why do we need the Lync SDK Controls, if they can not be used in UI Suppression mode? For example, MyStatusArea control or other.

Answer (score 2):

The Lync controls provides value in 2 use cases as far as I can see:

1. For use when building an app that automates Lync
2. For use in a Conversation Window Extension Silverlight application

In these cases, having to code the functionality that the controls provide would be quite a lot of effort, so there's a productivity gain to be had by using the controls.

Having said that, it *is* a shame that the controls can't be used in UI suppression mode.

One reason is that for some controls, it doesn't make sense to run them in UI suppression mode. For example, the StartInstantMessagingButton control fires up a new conversation window - this conversation window would not be displayed in UI suppression mode (given that the UI is suppressed!)

Another possible reason (my own take on it) is that UI suppression mode is to be used when a company wants to restrict users to a limited subset of Lync functionality. e.g. they may wish to embed the ability to send an IM to a set of users in an HR department, but not allow the ability to call any other users, or add other contacts etc.

Allowing the controls to work when in Suppressed UI mode would mean that a non-developer could open Visual Studio, create a WPF/Silverlight app, drag on some controls and effectively bypass the restrictions that the company imposed. (of course, as it stands a developer could still create an app that uses the raw API to bypass those restrictions, but it would be a lot more work).

I may be way off on this, and there may be other technical reasons for the limitation.

If you're happy that this is the right answer, could you mark it as accepted using the tick, to help any other users visiting this post? Thanks

Comment: I agree with some things, but a little... I can't agree with Microsoft developers. Why can't I use this controls in suppression mode? If I can not use them - I must write a lot of code. I want to integrate Lync in my application, but I do not need Lync Client visible. It can be very stupid to see the same controls in different programs, that are running at one time. So, are there objective reasons?

Comment: No, I don't think it's anything to do with COM interop - the underlying COM components will be available to the controls regardless of whether the UI is in Suppressed mode or not